# React-native Tab-navigator not displayed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

i would like to display a TabNavigator in my app.For that i was using [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab) but now i had to restructure my code, and it is not working anymore.
Here is my code :

The main class :

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View,Text, WebView,StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import { TabNavigator } from "react-navigation";
const Navigation = TabNavigator({
  Prod: { screen: Prod },
  ContinuousDeployment: { screen: ContinuousDeployment },
});
export default class Mattermost extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = ({
            MMAUTHTOKEN : null,
            BASICAUTH : null,
        });
    }
    render(){
        if(this.state.MMAUTHTOKEN === undefined || this.state.MMAUTHTOKEN === null){
            return(
                /*Another page , not the tab*/
            );
        }
        else if(this.state.BASICAUTH === undefined || this.state.BASICAUTH === null){
                return(
                    /*Another page , not the tab*/
                );
        }
        else{
            return <View>{Navigation}</View>;
        }
    }
```

And here is the class of one of my pages :

```js
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {View,Text,StyleSheet} from 'react-native';


export default class Prod extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    static navigationOptions = {
        tabBarLabel: 'Prod',
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
            <Image source={require('../Images/Icones/jenkins.png')} style={[styles.icon, {tintColor: tintColor}]}/>
        ),
    };

    put(){
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>Prod</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  icon: {
    width: 26,
    height: 26,
  },
});
```

It was working great before, but now it display a white screen, no tab , and without any warning or errors. If someone could help me it would be very cool ! Thanks in advance, Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this

```js
return <View>{Navigation}</View>;
```

to

```js
return <View><Navigation /></View>;
```

or

```js
return <Navigation />;
```

should fix this problem.

Comment: Damn , that was very simple... Thanks a lot